# Is there a better way to write s.substring so my code doesn't fail when having one character

Tags: java

When writing 'Hello' as my string, my output is 'He'. The same when writing 'He' as my string, my output is also 'He'. I have added a piece of code that states when the string is bigger then one character, then it should just print the character itself.

This seems very basic but somehow I get an error when only giving one character such as 'H' as my string. It says: `String index out of range: 2`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "o";
    String s1 = s.substring(0,2);


    if (s.length() >= 1 ) 
    {
    System.out.println(s);    
    }
    else 
    {
    System.out.println(s1);    
    } 

}

}
```

Answer (score 11):

Alternative:

```
s.substring(0, Math.min(2, s.length()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check this before calling `String.substring()`. You can use a ternary operator `? :` to make the code shorter:

```
String s = "a"
String o = s.substring(0, s.length() > 2 ? 2 : s.length());
System.out.println(o); // a
```

Answer (score 2):

When the string only have one character, you still run the `String s1 = s.substring(0,2);` , which will try to access the second character, and you get an out of range exception.

You could write your code as:

```
 String s = "o";
 String s1 = s;


if (s.length() > 2) {
    s1 = s.substring(0,2);
}
System.out.println(s1);
```

That way you only make a substring of `s` when it has more than 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code

```
class test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String s = "o";

  if (s.length() <= 1) {
   System.out.println(s);
  } else {
   String s1 = s.substring(0, 2);
   System.out.println(s1);
  }

 }
}
```

We cannot have a substring whose length is greater than the provided string's length, and hence those errors.